# Remove results if id has specific value with multiple values

Tags: sql-server

The title doesn't help and hopefully I can explain this right.
I need to exclude the PartNum from a query if it is in the KARDEX bin. These parts have multiple bins. If a part has the Kardex bin I want to exclude the part.
Here's sample data.

[image]

So I want to exclude 100217 and 101104-003 but keep the others.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't include sufficient details in your question, I can only give you a basic idea how that should work:

```sql
select *
from yourtable x
where not exists (
  select 1
  from yourtable y
  where x.partnum = y.partnum  -- same part number
  and y.binnum = 'KARDEX'      -- but in the KARDEX bin
)
```